# XNA ContentManager.Load causes string allocation

Tags: xna, c#, xna-content-pipeline

I was running the Visual Studio memory profiler on a project and noticed that an enormous amount of strings were being instantiated. It turns out that `ContentManager.Load` appears to create a new string instance each time it's called.  This might not be a big deal on a PC, but on other platforms like the Xbox, it quickly forces a garbage collection.

Maybe I'm just a bit naive, but I assumed that `ContentManager` would manage my game content, given the name and all. This led to calling the Load method every time I needed a texture (like during `Draw`), but it seems like this approach apparently can't work since the `Load` method will allocate strings, even if it's not allocating extra memory for already-loaded textures.

Is there a good solution to this? The obvious answer seems to be to maintain my own references to the textures and not call `Load` if they've already been loaded...but that seems like precisely what the `ContentManager` should be doing.

Comment: You shouldn't be loading things on every draw call. Of course that's going to slow things down even if `ContentManager` caches them (which it does), because as you said, it allocates strings and has to look up the resources in the cache. You should load everything in the `Load` method that gets called once when your game screen/level/whatever is initialized and assigns the newly loaded objects to member variables. You would then reference those variables in your `Draw` call.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your solution to the problem is correct - hold your own references.

In my games I take it a step further with `class Asset<T>`. Basically:

- The `Asset<T>` type can exist in a not-yet-loaded state (a public field).

  - `Asset<T>` has some helper methods that make skipping unloaded assets easier.
- `Asset<T>` objects are allocated by a class that implements `AssetManager<T>` (one implementation for each content type I care about). `AssetManager<T>` doesn't care about whether or not it's re-allocating duplicates. It is thread-safe.
- `AssetManager` keeps track of already allocated objects and delegates calls to the various `AssetManager<T>` implementations. It is thread-safe. It is a `static` class (*yeah, yeah, I know it shouldn't be*).
- When the `GraphicsDevice` is ready I spin up a secondary thread that goes and loads content from `Asset<T>` objects that are not yet loaded (basically just pop off a queue and load).
- The `AssetManager` has a `DoneLoading` property that checks if the load queue is empty.
- One implementation even had asset groups. This was used to e.g. keep universal assets in memory between levels.

The raw interface of these types would be:

```
public class Asset : IDisposable
{
  internal void Load(ContentManager mgr); // Call loader and assign it to Asset then set IsLoaded to true.
}

public class Asset<T> : Asset
{
  public string Name { get; } // Optional, I took it out for release builds.
  public T Asset { get; } // Throws exception if not loaded.
  public bool IsLoaded { get; }

  public Asset(Func<ContentManager, T> loader); // Store loader in a private field.
  public bool Use(Action<T> usage)
  {
    if (IsLoaded) { usage(Asset); return true; }
    return false;
  }
  /* E.g.
    foo.Use(tex =>
    {
      spriteBatch.Draw(tex, ...);
    });
  */
}

public class AssetManager<T>
{
  public Asset<T> Allocate(string name);
}

public static class AssetManager
{
  public static bool DoneLoading { get { return _notYetLoaded.Count == 0; } }
  private static Queue<Asset> _notYetLoaded;
  public static Asset<T> Get<T>(string name);
}
```

Advantages of this system:

- You can ask for content before the `GraphicsDevice` is ready and they will be loaded when it is.
- Load screens 'know' when to progress onto the game by simply checking the `DoneLoading` property on the `AssetManager`.
- `ContentManager` is only asked for resources once - you won't get the string allocation problem.
- You can animate your load screens.
- By using `Asset<T>.Use` correctly assets would automagically appear in your game at runtime (e.g. if they are loaded inside the actual game state).

With this system I saw no significant problems with grabbing assets when graphical objects were constructed (and storing them in fields), but grabbing them each frame is just wasteful and lazy.

Also be careful about your ordering when it comes to adding and loading assets. You should always add the assets to the dictionary before they are loaded - this fixes cyclic dependency problems.

Comment: You asked for a rope to hang yourself with and I gave you a bazooka to shoot yourself with ;).

Comment: Out of curiosity, is calling `.Use` with an anonymous method every `Draw` less efficient than, say, creating an `OnDraw` event and subscribing to it once on `Load`?

Comment: @RichardMarskell-Drackir you have the wrong idea with the event, but yes `Use` is marginally less efficient. Another way would be to write a implicit conversion (`public static implicit operator T (Asset<T> asset)`) that either throws an exception or returns the asset and manually use and `if (asset.IsLoaded)` everywhere.

Answer (score 4):

ContentManager is for **loading** content, not keeping a reference to it*.  Your "solution" as you call it is actually the way it **should** be done.

A good rule of thumb is *only call `ContentManager.Load<T>()` when you **need** to load the content into memory*. Once it is there keep your own reference to it.

Oh, and don't forget to call `ContentManager.Unload()` when you are done with everything in that scene.

<sup>Yes, internally it will do that, that is more for shared resources than anything else</sup>

Comment: Downvoter care to explain?